# tf_conversions / posemath / pykdl problem with fromMsg

Tags: ros, tf-conversions

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a bug in the python kdl wrapper, leading to unexpected behavior when working on KDL frames.
I felt like posting it here since other people might run into it before it's fixed, and they would most probably look for a solution here.

The simple remedy is of course to assign whatever is returned from fromMsg to a variable before usage.

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('tf')
roslib.load_manifest('tf_conversions')
import tf_conversions.posemath as pm
roslib.load_manifest('geometry_msgs')
import geometry_msgs
pose_msg = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
pose_msg.position.x = 100
print pm.fromMsg(pose_msg).p
#[           0,           0,           0]
pose = pm.fromMsg(pose_msg)
print pose.p
#[         100,           0,           0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27685/tf_conversions-/-posemath-/-pykdl-problem-with-frommsg/) by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 481 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) on 2012-02-17**:
We can create this error using kdl:
import PyKDL as kdl
kdl.Frame(kdl.Rotation.Quaternion(0,0,0,1),kdl.Vector(100,200,300)).p
Out[9]: [2.56735e-316,6.93179e-310, 300]
kdl.Frame(kdl.Rotation.Quaternion(0,0,0,1),kdl.Vector(100,200,300)).p[0]
Out[10]: 0.0 # which is not 100!

**Comment by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) on 2012-02-29**:
Turns out it's a general problem with SIP. Whenever we have a struct C { Member m; } and access from from a an instantiation C().m, the instantiated object gets garbage collected while .m still points to the memory held by C++ directly. It seems like there is no way to do this right in SIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer by TomTUM: Turns out it's a general problem with SIP. Whenever we have a struct C { Member m; } and access from from a an instantiation C().m, the instantiated object gets garbage collected while .m still points to the memory held by C++ directly. It seems like there is no way to do this right in SIP.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0